# How to map to URL in a bootstrap table?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am pulling data that gives me a news article title and url separately:

[image]

I would like to combine the url and title. Here is how I am mapping the table:

```
<Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>URL</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
{props.value.map(item => (
  <tbody key={item.id}>
      <tr>
        <td>{item.title}</td>
        <td>{item.url}</td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
))}
```

);

So I want the title to be a link to the url, instead of having the separation that is currently occurring. How can I accomplish this? The unique thing is each title has a different URL - all the resources I have found only show mapping for a single URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

```
<Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
{props.value.map(item => (
  <tbody key={item.id}>
      <tr>
        <td><a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
))}
```

Comment: I guess `href` should be ``${item.url}``.

Comment: Nice, worked well. Any way to make the link open a new tab instead of open in current tab?

Comment: set `target` attr, [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), `<a href={item.url} target="_blank" rel="noopener">{item.title}</a>` @Satoshi24